# Adding one day to Javascript date + unique formatting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I've inherited a project for a company I'm working for.  Their dates are recorded in the following format:

March 18th, 2011 would be listed as "18 Mar 2011".

April 31st, 2010 would be listed as "31 Apr 2010".

How would I use Javascript to add one day to a date formatted in the above manner, then reconvert it back into the same format?

I want to create a function that adds one day to "18 Mar 2011" and returns "19 Mar 2011".  Or adds 1 day to "30 Jun 2011" and returns "1 Jul 2011".

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all there is no 31st of April ;)

To the actual issue, the date object can understand the current format when passed as an argument..

```
var dateString = '30 Apr 2010'; // date string
var actualDate = new Date(dateString); // convert to actual date
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+1); // create new increased date

// now extract the bits we want to crete the text version of the new date..
var newDateString = ('0'+newDate.getDate()).substr(-2) + ' ' + newDate.toDateString().substr(4,3) + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear();

alert(newDateString);
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jGwYY/1/

---

The same extraction using (*the better supported*) [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) instead of `substr`

```
// now extract the bits we want to crete the text version of the new date..
var newDateString = ('0'+newDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' + newDate.toDateString().slice(4,7) + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear();
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jGwYY/259/

Comment: Perfect thanks!  Appreciate it, I need to get much more comfortable with the Date APi I guess.

Comment: Something to mention is that months are indexed by 0. Hence `Apr` corresponds to `3`.

Comment: ++++++++++++++1 Great help

Comment: Careful with substr(-2). This will not work in IE8 and below.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to convert the date string into a Date object, add one day to the object, and then convert back. Please have a look at the API docs for [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Most (all?) browsers will be able to parse that date string in with a simple

```
var parsedDate = new Date(dateString);
```

Once you have a Date object you can add a day and output a formatted date string using something like [underscore.date](https://github.com/timrwood/underscore.date).

If you discover that some browsers can't parse that date format then you can write a pretty simple regex that will pull apart the date string into its constituent parts, and then build a Date instance by hand.

Also I would strongly recommend doing the parsing in a separate function, and to try and keep dates in a Date representation as much as possible. Parse the string into a date as soon as you can, and format it back into a string as late as you can.